# How to crawl website that uses Direct Web Remoting (DWR) to return Javascript that manipulates page's HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler, dwr

I am having issues crawling a particular website that seems to generate all its content dynamically using DWR. The page source reveals a small amount of HTML as a 'shell' which contains no links that I want to crawl. Instead, I see POST requests whose responses contain only Javascript:

```
throw 'allowScriptTagRemoting is false.';
//#DWR-INSERT
//#DWR-REPLY
var a1 = {}; var a2 = {}; var a3 = {}; // ... etc.
a1.configs=a3;a1.defaultSite=true;a1.defaultValues=a4; // ... etc.
```

and a bunch of stuff totaling about 150 lines.

I understand that this is how DWR works, but I'd like to know how web crawlers generally get around this. Are there ways for it to execute the javascript from the AJAX's response and then wait for the HTML to finish being edited?

I feel this is different from traditional Ajax requests since they may return HTML and the DOM is updated as soon as the Ajax request is complete. Or, they return some data, and the rest of the page's Javascript updates the DOM. In either case though, there is no need to execute the response afterward.

Any insight would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what platform you are trying to crawl the website, but you can try using PhantomJS to run the JavaScript and render the site. If you are trying to crawl it with AJAX from another site, you can send a request to your own server that runs PhantomJS in the back-end and displays the rendered content as the output.